# rendering blocks and child blocks within a theme

Tags: magento, block

I am currently trying to get a better understanding of how blocks work in Magento. I have looked at some of the files to get a better idea and it has helped a little, but they are a too to complex for my limited skills at the moment and I still do not have proper understanding of what is going on and how to implement them into my site. I realise they are essential to understand for working with Magento so I thought I would set up a list of things to try and achieve:

1. display a block (done)
2. display a block and child block
3. display a block within a magento layout
4. position a block on the page of a magento layout
5. learn the most commonly used 'type' attributes and when to use them

So far I have put together
_index_index
Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<frontend>
    ....
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <learningblocks>
                <file>Namespace/Module/childblocks.xml</file>
                <file>Namespace/Module/blocks.xml</file>
            </learningblocks>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Namespace/Module/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Namespace_Module_IndexController
    extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout('learningblocks')->renderLayout();
    }

    public function blocksAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout('blocknode')->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

frontend/base/default/layout/namespace/module/blocks.xml

```
<layout>
    <blocknode>
        <block type="core/text" name="blocktest" output="toHtml" >
            <action method="setText">
                <args>some text to display on screen</args>
            </action>
        </block>
    </blocknode>
</layout>
```

The above worked as expected and displayed the string 'some text to display on screen' on a white page. But thats all i've been able to do, I cannot get child blocks to render onto the screen and I cannot display anything within a theme, let alone try and move it about within that theme

Below is one of my attempts that I cant seem to get to work. Why is this not working?

frontend/base/default/layout/namespace/module/childblocks.xml

```
<layout>
    <abcde>
        <block type="core/template" name="childblocks" output="toHtml" template="namespace/module/childblocks.phtml">
            <block type="core/text" name="anyname">
                <action method="setText">
                    <args>Some text to add to this page</args>
                </action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </abcde>

    <learningblocks_index_index>
        <update handle="abcde" />
    </learningblocks_index_index>
</layout>
```

frontend/base/default/template/namespace/module/childblocks.phtml

```
<p>from the childblock.phtml page</p><?php $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

NB: I have changed the namespaces and module names to be more generic, in the hope it is easier to read (they wern't very well chosen names).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a complete answer, but it may help those who have struggled with the same problem. I have not gone into great depth as I assume if your searching for an answer you will have already read [THIS ARTICLE](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates) and that covers it all, I assume you have the same issue as I did i.e. a misunderstanding of what you had learnt from this tutorial.

On reading this answer please be aware I am very new to Magento and there could be some inaccuracies in here, if there are I am sure someone will correct me and edit accordingly.

Firstly this is wrong

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout('learningblocks')->renderLayout();
}
```

It should be this

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}
```

and then you will have to map learningblocks node in layout xml to that action module_controller_action. Doing this will display the block in the page within your theme.

So to render a child block

Add something like this in you layout.xml

```
<module_controller_action>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="module/blockname" name="unique_name" output="toHtml" template="path/toyou/template.phtml" >  
            <block type="module/blockname" name="another_unique_name" output="toHtml" template="path/toyou/template.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</module_controller_action>
```

then in your template file echo out

```
$this->getChildHtml('another_unique_name')
```

If you want to remove blocks from your page use the remove node such as

```
<remove name="right"/>
<remove name="left"/>
```

[This page will offer a list of attributes that can be used](http://www.scribd.com/doc/20939945/Magento-Layout-Files-Reference) to be honest I found that looking through the magento files helped more than that page though